# Qna Maker: While Opening Knowledge base, getting error

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

While opening my Knowledge bases in QnA Maker I'm getting the following error:
Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key.

How can we update the subscription key and where we need to update them?

Comment: "While opening my Knowledge bases in QnA Maker": in QnA Maker portal?

Comment: yes in the portal.

Comment: When did you access those KB before? Have you updated to the GA version?

Comment: i used 2 weeks back.. what is GA version and where should I update it?

Comment: You can learn about the GA [here](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/05/07/announcing-general-availability-of-qnamaker/), and the steps to migrate to the GA is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/migrate-knowledge-base), also make sure you're using the [old portal](https://www.qnamaker.ai/old) if you created your KB before the GA

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but now if i try to open my KB then I'm getting error: Oops!! Something went wrong.
Knowledge base not found.
So i cannot open and export my KB.